# How to modify Select2 AllowClear functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have created a custom adapter for Select2 Selection where I want to show input field directly in the select instead of dropdown.

```js
$.fn.select2.amd.define('SearchableSingleSelection', [
  'select2/utils',
  'select2/selection/single',
  'select2/selection/eventRelay',
  'select2/dropdown/search'
], function(Utils, SingleSelection, EventRelay, DropdownSearch) {
  var adapter = Utils.Decorate(SingleSelection, DropdownSearch);
  adapter = Utils.Decorate(adapter, EventRelay);

  /**
   * Renders the custom Select2 element with a search field inside.
   * @returns {jQuery} The rendered Select2 element.
   */
  adapter.prototype.render = function() {
    var $rendered = DropdownSearch.prototype.render.call(this, SingleSelection.prototype.render);
    this.$searchContainer.hide();
    if (this.options.options.minimumResultsForSearch === Infinity) {
      this.$searchContainer.find('input').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    if (this.options.options.maximumInputLength) {
      this.$searchContainer.find('input').attr("maxlength", this.options.options.maximumInputLength);
    }
    this.$element.siblings('.select2').find('.selection').prepend(this.$searchContainer);
    return $rendered;
  };

  var bindOrigin = adapter.prototype.bind;
  adapter.prototype.bind = function(container) {
    var self = this;
    bindOrigin.apply(this, arguments);
    container.on('open', function() {
      self.$selection.hide();
      self.$searchContainer.show();
      self.$searchContainer.find('input')[0].focus();
    });
    container.on('close', function() {
      self.$searchContainer.hide();
      self.$selection.show();
      self.$searchContainer.find('input')[0].blur();
    });
  };

  return adapter;
});
```

Now I want to customise the AllowClear functionality too since it is not working. How can I modify AllowClear.prototype.update & AllowClear.prototype._handleClear functions?